# Send a message from a background service via notifyicon

Tags: background, notifyicon

I have a windows service that I created in Windows Forms because I wanted to use the notifyIcon tool to send intermittent messages to the system tray notification area.

When I run the code directly everything works well. But when I run it as a background service, nothing happens.

I have attempted to debug by attaching to the background service from within Visual Studio, and the debugger confirms (via triggered breakpoints) that notifyicon is being accessed - but nothing happens.

To check that the problem was in the notifyicon itself, I placed a beep just before the call to notify - but the beep does not sound either.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Noel Macara

Comment: IIRC, when you run the code directly, it runs in Session ID 1 (on which the current user is connected). When running it as a service it runs in Session ID 0 (which has no access to beep/notifications by default). Can you confirm that via Task Manager -> More Details -> Details -> Add column 'Session ID' ?

Comment: Thank you for that. Your answer made me look at the Task Manager and I don't think that the different session IDs have anything to do with it - but the Task Manager did reveal that UAC Virtualisatioin is Not Allowed. I under my process. I suspect that the problem has something to do with that. Thanks agein. I shall keep looking.